# collection that changes size dynamically but allows to reuse objects and do not allocate memory

Tags: c++

From network I receive certain entries. This is stock exchange quotes, something like that: "HP 100 1", "HP 101 10", "HP 102 3" etc.

One network packet may contain one or more entries. Theorethically there is limit how much entries may network packet contain: `Maximum transmission unit of the network / sizeof(entry)`. However this limit may vary depending on which machine and where application is launched.

Every time I receive new packet I need to store entries in collection. I dropping previous items and just place new items in the collection. Let's assume that now collection contains CURRENT number of items and I've receive NEW number of items, than:

- If NEW <= CURRENT collection should allow me to 1) reconfigure first NEW items. 2) resize collection length to NEW 3) do not drop the rest of the items, cause they will be reused during next packets processing
- If NEW > CURRENT collection should 1) ensure that capacity of collection is enough to store NEW items, if it is not enough than resize a collection and instatiate required number of items. 2) allow me to reconfigure NEW items.

So the idea is simple:

- collection should grow and shortly it's size should become ~`Maximum transmission unit of the network / sizeof(entry)`
- after that no new objects should be allocated, only already allocated objects should be reused and reconfigured. even when collection length decrease to say 1, the rest 1000 items should not be dropped, because on the next step collection length will become again 1000 and I will reuse these items.

If any of existent `stl` or `boost` collections could be used like that or I have to write my own?

Actually I can use pure array for that - but most missing part would be "autogrowing" as I can not compute the maximum size even at runtime.

Another option - i can use any of existent collection but in addition store myself the "size" of it. And never decrease the size of collection instead always use "my" copy of "size". As I never decrease collection size it will never drop items. This should work but will be a little bit "tricky".

Answer (score 0):

The capacity of an [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) increases as needed, but doesn't decrease. This seems to fit your needs.

Simply [push](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) items into the vector, and [clear](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/clear) the vector when finished. Then re-use the vector for the next set of items.

Or alternatively, you can [resize](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) the vector, and place items at a given [index](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at). Repeatedly do so on the same vector for subsequent sets of items.

In both cases, the vector will have retained its capacity.

You can even [reserve](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) an initial capacity for the vector.

Note that technically, this does not re-use the objects (except for existing objects in the resize option), but it re-uses the allocated memory. In practice though, since you're modifying the objects every time, this should be sufficient (especially when using POD objects).

Comment: assume that vector has 1 item now an capacity is 2. how can i increase it size to 2 and reconfigure second item after that? note `push` will not work because I have nothing to push actually. I need to get existent item, reconfigure it and increase size.

Comment: [`std::vector::resize`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) allows you to resize the vector to 2, after which you can access the second item, and fill it as needed.

Comment: If you want to store something "in the same place as the old one", then just find the old one, like this `index = v.find(stuff_to_find); /* check index is valid */ v[index] = new_value;`

Comment: i think vector will not work as according to doc `resize` destroys items `If n is smaller than the current container size, the content is reduced to its first n elements, removing those beyond (and destroying them).`

Comment: yes, but you don't need them any more, so why does that matter ? If you later resize the vector back to a larger size, the objects will be there again for you to modify. Especially with POD types, this isn't an issue.